# Digital Pricing Gun

Tags: printer, barcode-scanner

I need digital pricing gun to replace [manual input price gun](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Price-MX-5500-Retail-Store-Pricing/dp/B007P7Z27M). It's needed to minimize human error while entering price or labeling the wrong product. It's must have :

1. Barcode Scanner
2. Price tag printer
3. The pricing gun can store data product and the price.

Basically the step is like this : user scan the barcode first, then the pricing gun will print the label price which is the price data stored in pricing gun.
Is there any digital pricing gun like this ?